# Pass file contents to NGRX effect in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following HTML/Angular in my component:

```html
<div class="block">
    <label id="lbl">File </label>
    <input #fileInput type='file'/>
    <button class="btn btn-sm"  (click)="_uploadFile()">Upload The JSON File</button>
</div>
```

The TS file for the component has:

```js
@Output() uploadFile = new EventEmitter();
    _uploadFile() {
    this.uploadFile.emit();
}
```

The module TS file:

```js
    uploadFile() {
        this.store.dispatch(new PageActions.UploadFile());
    }
```

The action file:

```js
export class UploadFile implements Action {
    readonly type = PageActionTypes.UploadFile;
    constructor(public payload: File) { }
}
```

The effects file:

```js
@Effect()
uploadFile$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(PACtions.PageActionTypes.UploadFile),
    map( action => action.payload ),
    // ...
);
```

I am trying to figure out how to get the files' contents (or file) from the component through the action to the effect to use FileReader.  The file being uploaded will be a valid JSON file and I need to get the JSON from that file.

I think I need to do `.emit()` in the component for something but not sure.

Comment: Why do you want to read file content ? Can you tell me more

Comment: It is a requirement to put the JSON back into the store's state.

Answer (score 1):

To get the contents of the JSON file, you will need to use FileReader.

Here is a simple implementation of it.

```
<div class="block">
  <label id="lbl">File </label>
  <input #fileInput type='file' (change)="onChange($event)"/>
  <button class="btn btn-sm"  (click)="uploadFile()">Upload The JSON File</button>
</div>
```

And on your component.ts, you listen to the change event which will be triggered when the user uploads the file. From there, after parsing the JSON values, we will store the object on the `uploadedData` property.

Clicking of the button will trigger the `uploadFile` method, and from there, you can dispatch the action to pass the values of `uploadedData` (which contains the object from the uploaded JSON file) for further manipulation on your redux/ngrx store.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  uploadedData: any;

  onChange(event) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => {
      const raw = (<FileReader>e.target).result as string;
      const res = JSON.parse(raw);
      this.uploadedData = res;
    }
    reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
  }

  uploadFile() {
    console.log(this.uploadedData);
    // this.store.dispatch(new PageActions.UploadFile(this.uploadedData));
  }

}
```

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ujxseb?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

In addition, you should not use `File` as the typings for the payload, as we have actually parsed the file content. You may use some other custom interface to define the typings for your uploaded data.

```
export class UploadFile implements Action {
  readonly type = PageActionTypes.UploadFile;
  constructor(public payload: any) { }
}
```

Comment: As a requirement, I need the user to click an upload button after the browse.

Comment: @cdub hi, it is actually not as complicated as it seems. After uploading the file, we can store the data on a property in the component class. Upon clicking the button, we can access the property, and dispatch the action which will take accept the object as a parameter. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @cdub any luck with implementing my solution?

Comment: The JSON is actually a download of the state of the app at a given point. When it's uploaded I need the app to use the JSON and put it in the store and make the app go back to that state. How is that accomplished? I believe I need a reducer and a refresh.

Comment: @cdub A reducer is all you need! That will be to update your state

Comment: I need more detail on how to connect everything.